# Transpose mutiple rows in one column MS access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Looking to transpose data below

3 rows

```
Order #         Carton       SKU    QTY Date       Hub  PODSTATUS
07232768343200  0           4384173 1   2018/08/13  CRB   X1
07331558939200  13746809    1724640 1   2018/08/19  CRB   X1
07332717287200  13746811    1724640 1   2018/08/19  CRB   X1
```

to

just one column

```
07232768343200
0
4384173
1
2018/08/13
CRB
X1
07331558939200
13746809
1724640
1
2018/08/19
CRB
X1
07332717287200
13746811
1724640
1
2018/08/19
CRB
X1
```

[image: final result]

any help is appreciated thanks!

RTam

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your columns are strings, you can use `union all`:

```
select order# from t union all
select carton from t union all
. . .
```

You may need to explicitly convert columns that are not strings.

Note that the results will have no particular order *because tables represent unordered sets*.  You should not depend on the ordering in the result set.  If you depend on that ordering, you should have an additional column that specifies the ordering.